# Java - Can a function return the same type as one of the input arguments?

Tags: java

I have two very similar functions in Java:

```
public Connector GetRelevantConnector(MyData myData, Connector c1, Connector c2) {
    if(myData.useC1()){
         return c1;
    } 
    return c2;
}
```

Similarly I have the following function:

```
public String GetRelevantConnector(MyData myData, String c1, String c2) {
    if(myData.useC1()){
         return c1;
    } 
    return c2;
}
```

The functions above have been simplified but anyway all of the logic inside the functions is dependent on myData for choosing c1 or c2. The functions are essentially duplicated code, I was wondering if Connector/String can be declared as generic type and the function's return type is whathever the generic input is. Is this possible?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, that's what Java's *generic methods* are for:

```
public <T> T GetRelevantConnector(MyData myData, T c1, T c2) {
    if(myData.useC1()){
         return c1;
    } 
    return c2;
}
```

See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/methods.html

Answer (score 1):

If you don't manipulate the objects `c1` and `c2` but just use them to pick one of them, then yes you can generify the function:

```
public <T> T GetRelevantConnector(MyData myData, T c1, T c2) {
    if(myData.useC1()){
         return c1;
    } 
    return c2;
}
```

However, if you do something with them (for example `c1.someMethod()` or `c2.someProperty`), then you should show more code to see if templating is possible.